# Loading UIImages for flip animation unbelievably slow

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using the `UIImageView` `animationImages` property to display a small flipbook animation. That works fine, but loading 35 frames that is only ~200kb takes over 4 seconds on an iPhone 7. This is the code I am using to load the frames:

```
//start timer
var imgListArray = [UIImage]()

for countValue in 0...34 {

    if let image = UIImage(named: "anim_\(countValue).jpg") {
        imgListArray.append(image)
    }
}
//end timer

self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray
```

Given that I can load in a multi-megabyte image in less than a second, I just can't believe it takes so long to load in these little frames (pixel dimensions are 507x189). I have tried using 8-bit and 24-bit PNGs and JPEGs and they all take about the same amount of time.

If I don't append the images to the array it takes about the same amount of time, so the only thing that it can be is calling `UIImage(named:)`.

Can anyone suggest a faster way to load these frames in or faster way to display a flip book animation?

Comment: This could be a stupid question, but, are you running the code on main thread?

Comment: Yes. I'll try dispatching it, but as soon as the images have populated I will need to update the view on the main thread. Since it seemed like this should be so fast, it seemed that a background thread shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Can you please post the full code of assigning images array to `animatedImages`?

Comment: Try with [imageWithContentsOfFile:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624123-imagewithcontentsoffile?language=objc) method instead of imageNamed:

Comment: Just tried using a background thread; might be slightly faster - but still over 3 seconds. I will post the code showing the array being assigned to `animatedImages` but the code that is slow is only the code shown.

Comment: @FahriAzimov thank you - I had forgotten about `imageWithContentsOfFile:` - and that did the trick! Now it takes about 0.01 seconds to load the frames. Please post as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You should be thanking @PuneetSharma ))

Comment: Ooops! You're right of course! Anyhow - thanks to both of you!